# What's the benefit of mpi derived datatypes

Tags: c, mpi

Let's suppose my 3d grid of procs needs to communicate 2d arrays with all nearest neighbors. I could simply store the 2d array as a 1d array to make the data contiguous and use send/recv. Can I expect any performance benefit if I used e.g. Mpi_type_vector instead?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can manually pack/unpack the data to/from a contiguous buffer or used a derived datatype.

- manual pack/unpack requires more code, more memory, but packing/unpacking time can be reduced by `OpenMP` for example.
- a derived datatype requires less code, less memory, but data is generally packed/unpacked under the hood and this is generally performed by a single thread.

Bottome line, using a derived datatype saves you copying data to/from a buffer, but might not always be the fastest option.

Comment: Just ran a couple of benchmarks on a Cray xe6 and it seems like using derived datatypes is about 10x as fast. I guess there's some optimization going on but I can't figure out what it might be. On my local machine on the other hand, using mpi derived datatypes results in larger communication time

Comment: great feedback ! under the hood packing/unpacking could be multithreaded, and/or the hardware could support sending/receiving non contiguous buffers.